# Getting a Document Object Model Using LUA?

Tags: dom, lua, roblox, httpservice

i wanted to get a DOM (Document Object Model) value but i don't know how to in Lua! I know how to simply print the value in the console in google chrome but i need it to keep updating (since it calculates the value before changing the player_value DOM)

If anybody could possibly help me with a conversion method it would greatly be appreciated as i've been searching for a method for ages.

Comment: What JS library you're using to run Lua?

Comment: I might of confused you with the tags, but basically, i'm using lua to get a Document Object Model from the HTML on a website, would this need a post request of some sort ? (Using RLua [Roblox Lua] ) - i need an 'innerText' element inside of it.

Comment: Do you have a whole html page as a Lua string?

Comment: Yes, sorry for late reply, was busy yesterday.

Comment: So, you need to parse html page to extract the text between some two tags?

Comment: Yes, it makes a request to a .js file, it doesn't use an api so no way i can use a JSON Decode. (Well at least i don't think since i've looked at requests and only found a PlayerAssets API)

Comment: Is the path of the DOM element on the page fixed?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm not good at looking into google javascript etc so i'll just show you the 2 things which might be what i'm trying to get, .JS https://www.rolimons.com/js/player2.js / HTML DOM : https://imgur.com/a/qGdoclO

Comment: so, you need just to extract the value inside `h5#player_value` element?

Comment: Yes, the number in "innerText" in the element.

Comment: `innerText = htmlpage:match'<h5[^>]+id="player_value">(.-)</h5>'`

Comment: ill try this soon, thanks.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff i can confirm that this didnt work, although it matched the number inbetween, it get's its value from the DOM element which replaced with "&nbsp;" / https://imgur.com/a/CzW45cB .

Comment: Does it mean the webpage you have in a Lua string contains `&nbsp;` instead of the number?

Comment: Yea, it uses a request to get the string.

Comment: You should analyze/debug JS code to find the request (or a sequence of requests).  It would be not easy.